# read only installation of phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I need to give some testers an pretty interface to our database. I'm not able to make any changes in the database such as adding a new user or change any permissions, but i have a user. I would like to use phpmyadmin with this user but block all write/delete/insert operations, they should only be allowed to view the data, not change it (I simply don't trust them, not to screw up anything).
I've been searching the web and the documentation, but so far nothing.
Can anyone help me figure this one out?
[edit: to clarify]
I'm hoping that there is some kind of feature in phpmyadmin to block any calls to mysql that changes the db.

Answer (score 0):

This need to achieved with MySQL grants, the user need to be given only READ permission in MySQL. Please see the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Eg:

```
GRANT SELECT ON db2.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, I was actually trying to do this without changing anything about the user, or adding another user for that matter. I'm hoping that there is some kind of feature in phpmyadmin to block any calls to mysql that changes the db.